# Gnu date input formats

Tags: command-line, bash, date

I am trying to get my head around the date input formats used in

```
date -d "something"
```

Specifically I am trying to understand the use of the "Day of week items". The manual page for date refers you to the following set of GNU pages for information on this topic: [gnu.org - date input formats](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats).

This covers the entire topic of date input formats for GNU. Specifically it says the following about "Day of week":

> 28.6 Day of week items
>
> The explicit mention of a day of the week will forward the date (only
>   if necessary) to reach that day of the week in the future.
>
> Days of the week may be spelled out in full: ‘Sunday’, ‘Monday’,
>   ‘Tuesday’, ‘Wednesday’, ‘Thursday’, ‘Friday’ or ‘Saturday’. Days may
>   be abbreviated to their first three letters, optionally followed by a
>   period. The special abbreviations ‘Tues’ for ‘Tuesday’, ‘Wednes’ for
>   ‘Wednesday’ and ‘Thur’ or ‘Thurs’ for ‘Thursday’ are also allowed.
>
> A number may precede a day of the week item to move forward
>   supplementary weeks. It is best used in expression like ‘third
>   monday’. In this context, ‘last day’ or ‘next day’ is also acceptable;
>   they move one week before or after the day that day by itself would
>   represent.
>
> A comma following a day of the week item is ignored.

Based on this information I would expect the following command to tell me the date of the third Thursday in 2016.

```
jonathan@Aristotle:~$ date -d "4/1 3 thursday" +"%y %m %d"
16 04 01
```

As you can see the day of week specification is accepted but ignored and the result is April 1, not the third Thursday. The documentation states that the "day of week" specification should add to the base date specification **if necessary**. Unfortunately, the rules behind **if necessary** are not given. Does anyone know how to make this work using the date command. I can obviously work around this problem with Bash scripting.

Comment: what were you expecting? It is used to "*forward* the date (only if necessary) to reach that day of the week in the *future*." So it is *relative* to the current time. eg: `date -d "next thursday"`. It is not straight forward to get the day of the week [relative to a non-current time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203747/how-do-i-get-the-bash-date-script-to-return-a-day-of-the-week-relative-to-a-non)

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, the day-of-week style is baked into `dateutils`:

```
$ dateconv 2016-04-03-04 -f %F
2016-04-21
```

which is the third Thursday of April 2016 as requested.

Alternatively, the input can be explicitly specified:

```
$ dateconv -i "%m/1 %c %A" "4/1 3 thursday"
2017-04-03-04
```

(I'm not sure what the /1 is in your example).

Disclaimer: I am the author of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a method that does not rely on the arcane syntax of the input to:

```
date -d
```

This function solves the problem:

```
function calculateTargetDay {
# Calculates the day in the month of the nth. weekday in month
# $1 is the current date stored in an array as yy mm dd integers
# $2 is the day of the week as an integer, Monday = 1
# $3 is the week of the month as an integer - first week = 1
# Returns the day of month in the $daymonth variable which should be defined in the main-line

daymonth=$(( $(date -d "${1[0]}-${1[1]}-1" +%u) - 1 )) # Get relative day in week of 1st. of month
# Calculate release day within month
daymonth=$(( $daymonth - $2 + 7 + (( $3 - 1) * 7 ) ))}  # Gives day in month of nth weekday in month
```

This encapsulates the calculation in a compact manner.